# Name of applications running on port in Perl or Java

Tags: java, windows, perl, networking

Xampp comes with a neat executable called xampp-portcheck.exe.  This responds with if the ports required are free, and if not, which applications are running on those ports.

I can check if something is running on a port, by accessing the netstat details, but how do I find out the application running on the port within Windows?

Comment: @Xetius I think I came up with a working solution. Please test it and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CPAN module [Win32::IPHelper](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32::IPHelper) provides access to `GetExtendedTcpTable` which provides the `ProcessID` for each connection.

[Win32::Process::Info](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32::Process::Info) gives information about all running processes.

Combining the two, we get:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32;
use Win32::API;
use Win32::IPHelper;
use Win32::Process::Info qw( NT );

use Data::Dumper;

my @tcptable;

Win32::IPHelper::GetExtendedTcpTable(\@tcptable, 1);

my $pi = Win32::Process::Info->new;
my %pinfo = map {$_->{ProcessId} => $_ } $pi->GetProcInfo;

for my $conn ( @tcptable ) {
    my $pid = $conn->{ProcessId};
    $conn->{ProcessName} = $pinfo{$pid}->{Name};
    $conn->{ProcessExecutablePath} = $pinfo{$pid}->{ExecutablePath};
}

@tcptable =
    sort { $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] }
    map  {[ sprintf("%s:%s", $_->{LocalAddr}, $_->{LocalPort}) => $_ ]}
    @tcptable;

print Dumper \@tcptable;
```

**Output:**

```
  [
    '0.0.0.0:135',
    {
      'RemotePort' => 0,
      'LocalPort' => 135,
      'LocalAddr' => '0.0.0.0',
      'State' => 'LISTENING',
      'ProcessId' => 1836,
      'ProcessName' => 'svchost.exe',
      'ProcessExecutablePath' => 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\svchost.exe',
      'RemoteAddr' => '0.0.0.0'
    }
  ],
  ...
  [
    '192.168.169.150:1841',
    {
      'RemotePort' => 80,
      'LocalPort' => 1841,
      'LocalAddr' => '192.168.169.150',
      'State' => 'ESTABLISHED',
      'ProcessId' => 1868,
      'ProcessName' => 'firefox.exe',
      'ProcessExecutablePath' => 'C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe',
      'RemoteAddr' => '69.59.196.211'
    }
  ],
```

*Phewwww* it was exhausting connecting all these dots.